# line numbered paragraph using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bad habit of writing overly long paragraphs that go on and on.  As a way of helping myself visually scan my document and find some paragraphs that desperately need to be broken up, I'd like some way to have line numbers next to my paragraphs.  Pure CSS would be neat, but since this is just for me, JS is also fine.  Wrapping each line in its own tag is not an option: this is a document in flux.  Bonus points: number every 5th line or something.  Hopefully my phrasing is clear; if not I can clarify.

(On an unrelated note: any opinions on how long a paragraph can get before it's too long?)

EDIT: Okay, based on the comment and the answer I've gotten so far, it seems I was hopelessly unclear.  Let's try again.  Suppose I have two paragraphs.  Paragraph one is ten lines long, in the current font, browser width, etc.  Paragraph two is very short, just 3 lines long.  Then I want the numbers 1 through 10 next to the first paragraph, and the number 1 through 3 next to the second paragraph.  Make sense?

Comment: did u expect the result like this https://codepen.io/elomatreb/pen/hbgxp

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for

If you are looking to number p tags with css,you can do it using css-counters

check this snippet

```css
.container {
  counter-reset: pcount;
}
p::before {
  content: counter(pcount) "):";
  counter-increment: pcount;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is p</p>
  <p>This is p</p>
  <p>This is p</p>
  <p>This is p >This is p >This is p >This is p >This is p >This is p >This is p >This is p >This is p</p>
  <p>This is p</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Browser support for counter: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters, incase anyone was looking for it